# Comparing two Vector Direction MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, vector

I have three vessels and the direction of these vessels is given by `V1`, `V2` and `V3`:

```
V1 = [0.7030  -0.7112]
V2 = [0.5099  -0.8602]
V3 = [-0.6799  -0.7333]
```

And here's their graphical visualization:

[image: vectors]

How can I find if `V3` is "approaching" `V2` (as shown in the figure) or "leaving" `V2`? I want to check if vessel #3 is part of vessel #1 or vessel #2, *i.e* if vessel #3 is branching from vessel #1 then `V3` is "away" from `V1` and "towards" `V2` (shown in figure) and in that case vessel #3 is part of vessel #1.

How do I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: This is more of a mathematical question than a programming one. You'd probably get a better answer on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com...)

Comment: Note that vectors typically only have direction, and not a location. So you may want to give a better definition of things like 'approaching'.

Comment: Also, what does your data represent? Are these coordinates? If so, you need two points to define the vectors (and their direction) distinctively.

Comment: @EitanT “How do I do this in Matlab” is a programming question.

Comment: @Gilles Had the question been "_this is my algorithm for this and that, how do I implement it in MALTAB_", I would've agreed. However, it lacks the "algorithm that does this and that" part, which is a purely mathematical problem, so it's a mathematical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to see if `V1` 'approaches' `V2`

Calculate the minimum distance between the first coordinate of `V1` and the line segment `V2`.
Do the same for the second coordinate of `V1`.

If the first coordinate is further than the second, consider `V2` to be approaching `V1`

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is take the dot product of the two direction vectors `s = V1.'*V3;`

Now if the answer is positive then the two vectors converge (point towards the same direction).

If the answer is negative the two vectors diverge (point away from each other)

When two two vectors are perpendicular the dot product is zero, and when they are parallel is is equal to 1.

**Why?**

Because the dot product represents the cosine of the angle between two vectors.

```
a · b = |a| |b| cos(θ)
```

When the angle is more than π/2 then the cosine is negative, and the vectors point "away" from each other.

Comment: The dot product between (V1, V3 ) and (V1, V2) are :C1= dot(V1,V3)

C1 =0.0436 and

>> C2= dot(V2,V3)

C2 =  0.2841, but both are positive where as s = V1.'*V3; gives matrix i.e. s =

   [-0.4780   -0.5155
    0.4835    0.5215] but not scalar. Can you elaborate your answer how you have predicted the convergence and divergence of vector from  s = V1.'*V3;

Comment: Maybe you need not only the directions, but the positions in order to figure where their lines intersect. If so please clarify the question, or provide more detail in the example of when they approach and when not.